# neo4j-import failed while import local CSV file

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to import a CSV file into the neo4j database, I adopted the sample online but I still failed.

I executed the following command under the 'import' directory:

`../bin/neo4j-admin import --into retail.db --id-type string --nodes:Customer customers.csv --nodes products.csv --nodes orders_header.csv --relationships:CONTAINS order_details.csv --relationships:ORDERED customer_orders_headers.csv`

Expectedly,the windows powershell should have results like:

```
IMPORT DONE IN 5s 212ms
Imported:
6 nodes
7 relationships 
12 properties
```

However,my actual result is

```
expected '--nodes 'to have at least 1 valid item,but had 0[]
```

and gave me some usage guidance of neo4j-admin import. I cannot tell what the problem was because my command seemed correct.

Comment: provide contents of `products.csv`, `orders_header.csv` & `order_details.csv` and others. Not entire contents but some sample

Comment: sample of products.csv:

Comment: sample of products.csv:   
productId:ID(Product) name price :LABEL
11                           Chocolate   10      Product;Food

sample of orders_header.csv:
orderId:ID(Order) date total customerId:IGNORE
1041 2015/5/10 130 23
1042 2015/5/12 20 42
sample of order_details.csv
:START_ID(Order) amount price :END_ID(Product)
1041 13 130 11
1042 2 20 11

Comment: I removed csv files into the bin directory ,and the previous mistake disappeared,.

Comment: However,there is still error
"
error in input data 
Caused by :Multiple suitable files found in zip file C:\Users\Emma\neo4j-community-3.1.0-windows\neo4j-community-3.1.0\bin\customer.csv,at lease [Content Types].xml and xl/ rels/workbook.xml.rels. Only a single file per zip file is supported

"

Comment: I dont quite understand because I just copied my csv files into the bin directory